# Why is the size of `char` 4 bytes in Rust?

Tags: rust

This code shows that `char` takes 4 bytes:

```
println!("char : {}", std::mem::size_of::<char>());
```

1. Why does it take 4 bytes?.
2. Does the size depend on the platform, or is it always 4 bytes?
3. If it's always 4 bytes, it is for something special?
4. Does the compiler guarantee some minimum size for the size of `char`?

*In https://play.rust-lang.org/ I also get 4 bytes*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all: a `char` in Rust is a unique integral value representing a Unicode Scalar value. For example, consider  (aka Pile of Poo, aka U+1F4A9), in Rust it will be represented by a `char` with a value of `128169` in decimal (that is `0x1F4A9` in hexadecimal):

```
fn main() {
    let c: char = "".chars().next().unwrap();
    println!(" is {} ({})", c, c as u32);
}
```

[On the playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bb945d140091e925865368e282eb9d93&version=stable&backtrace=0).

With that said, the Rust `char` is 4 bytes because 4 bytes is the smallest power of 2 number of bytes which can hold the integral value of any Unicode Scalar value. The decision was driven by the domain, not by architectural constraints.

---

*Note: the emphasis on Scalar value is that a number of "characters" as we see them are actually graphemes composed by multiple combining characters in Unicode, in this case multiple `char` are required.*

Comment: I don't know why that emoji is kind of popular among developers, funny tho. However, it is good to use something like  instead of that emoji. (opinion)

Comment: @thebluetropics: Developers are just oversized children, what did you expect? :)

Answer (score 10):

`char` is four bytes.  It is *always* four bytes, it will always *be* four bytes.  Four bytes it be, and four bytes shall it remain.

It's not for anything special; four bytes is simply the smallest power of two in which you can store any Unicode scalar value.  Various other languages do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

**Char** is four bytes, it doesn't depend on the architecture.

Why? According to UTF-8 Wikipedia's article.

> The first 128 characters (US-ASCII) need one byte. The next 1,920
>   characters need two bytes to encode. Three bytes are needed for
>   characters in the rest of the Basic Multilingual Plane, which contains
>   virtually all characters in common use. Four bytes are needed for
>   characters in the other planes of Unicode.

So if you want to represent **any possible** Unicode character the compiler must save 4 bytes.

You should also consider Byte Alignment: http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/ByteAlignmentAndOrdering.htm

Comment: Note that `char` does not store a UTF-8 code point. `char` is actually an UTF-32 code point, that is, just a Unicode scalar value.

Comment: I actually saw this behavior when looking at the alignment of struct, I thought, char stores, ASCII only but I see no

Comment: all the more amazing, in this light is the theories offered here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html , namely: "As always, remember that a human intuition for 'character' may not map to Unicode's definitions. For example, emoji symbols such as '❤️' can be more than one Unicode code point; this ❤️ in particular is two:" <-- In UTF-32 you have only 1 code point for everything...

Comment: @VladimirMatveev You're mixing up terminology. UTF-8 has 8-bit code **units** and UTF-32 has 32-bit code **units**. They do not have different code points, which are just values between 0 and 0x10FFFF, but they encode them differently into code units. Rust `char` is not a code point but a Unicode scalar value, which has the same range but excludes the surrogate code point values. The surrogate code points are used by UTF-16 to allow it to represent all Unicode scalar values. Valid UTF-8 or UTF-32 shouldn't decode to a surrogate code point, but can decode to any scalar value and thus `char`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev There is no such thing as a UTF-8 code point or a UTF-32 code point. There are just code points, which are numbers in the abstract sense. UTF-8 and UTF-32 encode these code points differently.

Comment: But one question remains: what encoding is the USV stored in? UTF-32, as mentioned in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/textual.html)? Probably doesn’t matter too much though as it’s just an opaque implementation detail.